# Balkan MO problem

Tags: combinatorics

Let $S = \{A_1,A_2,\ldots ,A_k\}$ be a collection of subsets of an $n$-element set $A$. If for any two elements $x, y \in A$ there is a subset $A_i \in S$ containing exactly one of the two elements $x, y$, prove that $2^k\geq n$.

This is a question from Balkan MO 1997, and I did not quite understand the question, so I could not make any attempt. Please help.

Comment: What part of the question do you not understand?

Comment: @Servaes I do not understand the definition of the subset.

Comment: Of what subset? The question is about a bunch of subsets $A_1,\ldots,A_k\subset A$ such that for all $x,y\in A$, there exists $A_i\subset A$ such that either $x\in A_i$ or $y\in A_i$, but not both.

Comment: @Servaes what about the other elements of $A$?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: @Servaes okay, first tell me, how many elements can $A_i s$ have?

Comment: Any number from $0$ to $n$; it is simply a subset of $A$.

Comment: @Servaes Then, suppose $A=\{1,2,3\}$, Now, we group this into 2 element sets, namely, $\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{3,1\}$. Suppose, among the first set, we choose 1, from the second, we have to choose 3, and in the last one, we get a contradiction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14835/discussion-between-servaes-and-swadhin).

Answer (score 7):

You have a set $A$ with $n$ elements.

Then there is a collection of $k$ sets $\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$, each of which is a subset of $A$, that is, $A_i \subseteq A$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$. You need to prove that

> If for any pair $x,y \in A$ there is a set $A_i$ that distinguishes between $x$ and $y$ (that is, contains exactly one of them), then there are many sets $A_i$, namely $2^k \geq n$.

For example for $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $A_1 = \{1,2\}, A_2 = \{2,3,4\}$ we have that $A_1$ distinguishes between $2$ and $3$, but not between $3$ and $4$. In fact no set distinguishes between $3$ and $4$.

Another instance might be $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $A_1 = \{1,2\}$ and $A_2 = \{1,3\}$. In this setting every pair of elements $x,y \in A$ is distinguishable by sets $A_1,A_2$, and indeed $2^2 \geq 4$.

**Hint:**

> Consider function $f : A \to \mathbb{N}$ given by \begin{align} f(a) = 1\cdot\chi_{A_1}(a) + 2\cdot\chi_{A_2}(a) + 4\cdot\chi_{A_3} + \ldots + 2^{k-1}\cdot\chi_{A_k}(a), \end{align}
>  where $\chi_{A_i}(x)$ is the [characteristic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $A_i$, i.e.
>  \begin{align} \chi_{A_i}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if }x \in A_i,\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{align}
>  Observe that for any element $a \in A$ we have $0 \leq f(a) \leq 2^k-1$.

**Solution:**

> In other words, if $n > 2^k$ then there are two elements $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. This in turn implies that $\chi_{A_i}(x) = \chi_{A_j}(y)$ for any $1 \leq i,j \leq k$, so no $A_i$ distinguishes these two elements.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: You make Balkan MO look so easy ...

Comment: @EwanDelanoy I don't know about Balkan MO, but from those MO which I do know, each has its share of easy problems (and I suspect that Balkan MO is no exception).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rephrasing: let $S=\{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ be a collection of subsets of an $n$-element set $A.$   Let $x,$ $y$ be a pair of elements of $A.$  We will say that $S$ has the *XOR property for $(x,y)$* if at least one element of $S$ contains only one of $x,$ $y.$  In other words, $S$ would fail to have the XOR property for $x,$ $y$ if every element of $S$ contained either both $x$ and $y$ or neither $x$ nor $y.$

The question asks you to prove that if $S$ has the XOR property for all pairs of elements of $A,$ then $S$ can't be too small.  In particular, $S$ must consist of at least $\log_2 n$ subsets of $A.$

Answer (score 0):

Well here another formulation of the solution. Look at the Boolian algebra generated by $A_i$. This algebra has at most $2^k$ atoms. Now remark that the atoms are exactly the singleton subsets of $A$.